# ConcurrentHashMap jdk 8 Uses TreeNodes instead of List .. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Hi i know the workings of `ConcurrentHashMap` before JDK 8. 
I also understood the code: it was pretty modular and not very hard to understand.

The code of `ConcurrentHashMap` in JDK 8 has changed a lot from its previous implementations.

Because this question was classified as too broad I will now try to be very specific.

CHMv8 uses a TreeBin (a variant of RedBlackTree) for buckets rather than a linked list.

So my question what is the main advantage of using TreeBin over a linked list?

[Source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java)

Comment: First, there's only ~3k lines of code.

Comment: Besides which, since when is 6K lines of code "enormous"?

Comment: @HotLicks 6KLOC is a pretty monstrous single class. CHM gets some slack for including a bunch of nested classes.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think the OP was also counting comments + javadoc in the 6k total

Comment: @dkatzel Obviously, but they don't add to the complexity of the code. It's not 6KLoC.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think i'll edit my question for better language.

Comment: @DaveNewton hi Dave i have edited my question focusing on  the main issue i wanted to ask. Thanks for pointing out why my question was unconstructive

Comment: @Todd if you think if the edited question is now constructive and not too broad please vote to reopen it. Or suggest me to make the question better or anyother place where i can get my answer. thanks all

Comment: It's still "too broad" as the term is used here. Stack Overflow is [a Q&A resource, not a help forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92115/228805). It's for specific questions about coding that can have definite correct answers. A question pointing to some code and asking in general terms for help understanding what it does or how it works is off-topic, as are requests for references, tutorials, or feature comparisons between products. You need to identify a specific question about the code--what part don't you understand, and what specifically don't you understand about it?

Comment: Also, ***include all relevant information in the question*** rather than linking. Please read the following advice on asking questions: [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR).

Comment: @AdiInbar thanks. I have narrowed down the question to be very specific. If you think if its not to broad. Please vote to reopen

Comment: @Eran Hi i edited my question to very specific, if you think its fine please vote for reopen

Comment: @DonBranson Hi i have edited my question to very specific, if you think its fine please vote for reopen

Comment: See http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180 “*In the case of high hash collisions, this will improve worst-case performance from O(n) to O(log n).*”

Comment: @Holger thanks for the link its valuable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main changes are to add `ConcurrentHashMap` specific implementations of the new Java 8 default `Map` methods with better concurrent implementations that rely on the internal details.  These changes required lots of new inner classes which bloat the .java file

For example, some of these methods include:

[compute(K key, BiFunction remappingFunction)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

[forEach(BiConsumer action)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

[merge(K key, V value, BiFunction remappingFunction)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Just to name a few.

I think this also shows why you usually shouldn't care about implementation details on how a class you don't have to maintain works.  As long as the class follows the contract laid out in its javadoc, you should be agnostic of how it works since the implementation details can change in the future.

Comment: thanks i was looking for this kind of response only. Implementation is important for me as am writing some niche data structures to handle concurrency but for very specific requirements.  I tried to take good things various HasHMap implementations and various trade off. i dont' need all the functionality of CHMv8 just some.. for example computeIfAbsent. Also wanted to know  how they take care of resizing?

Comment: <i>I think this also shows why you usually shouldn't care about implementation details on how a class you don't have to maintain works</i> Until you run into problems, of course.